# Plotting columns as series

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe which has 12 columns (one for each month of the year) and an id. Each record in this dataframe corresponds to the transaction amount(in dollars) a customer has made over the course of last twelve months. I want to plot these columns as series. And I also want to plot all the customers in the dataframe. The x-axis will be the month index and y-axis will be dollar value. So basically for each customer I need a line or series chart on the same graph.

Code for generating random data

```
a <- data.frame(id = seq(1,1000,1))
b <- data.frame(replicate(12,sample(1000:100000,1000,rep=TRUE)))
df <- cbind(a,b)
```

This is what I tried but its not what I want

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
df_lg <- melt(df, id = 'id') # convert from wide to tall
ggplot(data=df_lg,
       aes(x=variable, y=value, colour=variable)) +
  geom_line()
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: There are 1000 `id` in your example dataset. It is just impossible to use color to visualize 1000 lines with color. You can try to change your `aes` call to `aes(x=variable, y=value, colour =id, group = id))`, but no way to interpret such plots.

Comment: as @ycw said you won't get any benefit by graphing that plot but in case you want to use base-R: `matplot(t(df), type = "l")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `group` to your aesthetics, so the `colour` and `group` should be the `id` variable you want in the legend.

```
ggplot(data=df_lg,
       aes(x=variable, y=value, colour=id, group = id)) +
  geom_line()
```